# Why do HTTP servers forbid underscores in HTTP header names

Tags: apache, http, nginx, rfc

I had a problem with a custom HTTP `SESSION_ID` header not being transfered by nginx proxy.

I was told that underscores are prohibited according to the HTTP RFC.

Searching, I found that most servers like [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers) define them as illegal in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) section 4.2, which says:

> follow the same generic format as that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]

[RFC822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) says:

> The  field-name must be composed of printable ASCII characters
>           (i.e., characters that  have  values  between  33.  and  126.,
>           decimal, except colon)

Underscore is decimal character 95 in the ASCII table in the 33-126 range.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

They are not forbidden, it's CGI legacy. See "[Missing (disappearing) HTTP Headers](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/?highlight=disappearing%20http%20headers#missing-disappearing-http-headers)".

> If you do not explicitly set `underscores_in_headers on;`, nginx will silently drop HTTP headers with underscores (which are perfectly valid according to the HTTP standard). This is done in order to prevent ambiguities when mapping headers to CGI variables, as both dashes and underscores are mapped to underscores during that process.

Comment: Just spent hours debugging why my rails app works fine in development but not on production because of this :/

Comment: Just spent hours debugging why my NodeJS app works fine in development but not on production because of this :/

Comment: Just spent hours debugging why my Flask app works fine in development but not on production because of this :/

Comment: Link to answer for Apache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440564/all-caps-http-headers-with-underscores-dropped-in-apache-2-4

Comment: Just spent 5 minutes debugging why my flask app doesnt work in dev or production and then thankfully stumbled upon this thread. Phew, dodged a bullet.

Comment: Just spend days checking why app works locally but not in prod (kubernetes with nginx ingress)

Comment: I spent a full 10 days to find this solution, because Google didn't find good answers to "nginx removes request headers".

Comment: I spent all morning debugging why it works on flask server but not AWS

Comment: just spent hours on this.

Comment: Just spent hours debugging why my Mendix app works fine in development but not on production because of this :/

Comment: nginx is hard to use and this is the last straw.  I think I'm gonna quit using it. Who in their right mind makes a web server with proxy-pass and drops headers? I think Nginx must be overrated. I'm gonna make a new one or just stick with Node or something like Bun, at least, that's what I want to do.

Comment: @user3413723  wish you the best

Answer (score 27):

Underscores in header fields are allowed per [RFC 7230, sec. 3.2.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2), but are uncommon.

Comment: I see it as "token" there, without a clear indication of what characters that allows?

Comment: "token" is defined in Section 3.2.6 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.6).

Comment: Thanks. I saw the top part previously, those definitions are too far down for how quickly I was scanning ;)