# Fail to access ember-data REST request headers from PHP SLIM framework

Tags: php, rest, ember-data, slim

This is the RESTAdapter code as in the Ember js guide:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'emberboot/api',

   headers: {
      'API_KEY': 'secret key'
  }
});
```

This is the code for getting headers from SLIM PHP. The get headers function is documented here http://docs.slimframework.com/#Request-Headers

```
// - http://localhost/emberboot/api/posts
// - $app->get('/posts', 'getPosts'); //get all post

function getPosts() 
{
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $key = $request->headers->get('API_KEY');

    //logging
    $file = 'headers.txt';
    file_put_contents($file, $key);
    ;
    ;
```

This is from the Chrome Developer Tool:

[image]

Clearly there is nothing wrong from the Ember-data part coz the header is there. However **THE LOGGING FILE: headers.txt** contain no text at all - **empty!**

**UDATED - ANSWERS AS SOLVE BY @engvrdr. Use dash instead of underscore**

**This is the RESTAdapter code UPDATED!**

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'emberboot/api',

   headers: {
      'API-KEY': 'secret key'
  }
});
```

The Slim PHP code updated:

```
function getPosts() 
{
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $headers = $request->headers;
    $apiKey = $headers->get('API-KEY');
    $file = 'headers.txt';
    file_put_contents($file, $apiKey);
    ;
    ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not much a slim expert but can you try? (In documentation request seems like a property not a method)

```
function getPosts() 
{
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
$key = $app->request->headers->get('API-KEY');

//logging
$file = 'headers.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $key);
```

Edit : 
As i found out it is an issue about underscores (_) in HTTP header names ([Why underscores are forbidden in HTTP header names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856136/why-underscores-are-forbidden-in-http-header-names))

if you change it to API-KEY it will work.

Comment: still failed - headers.txt is empty

Comment: @rosely-kumoi i've updated the answer can you try again?

Comment: still failed - I already submit problem posts at the Slim website - http://help.slimframework.com/ - waiting for their reply

Comment: w00t using dash is indeed working. Thank you, you are awesome!