# HTTP headers in Django

Tags: django, http-headers, tastypie

I need to perform some logic based on cucsom headers. I'm using Chrome's  postman to add the headers.

But it seems like I can only add them when the header name doesn't have a '_' 
Is there any reason for this ?

ideally i would like to add a header somthing like `'MY_HEADER'` and access it via `request.META['MY_HEADER']`, right now I'm adding it as `'MYHEADER'` and accessing it via `request.META['MYHEADER']`

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856136/why-underscores-are-forbidden-in-http-header-names

Comment: More common to use dashes ('-') instead of underscores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you vanadium23, Turns out Nginx was making changes. Full answer here [Why underscores are forbidden in HTTP header names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856136/why-underscores-are-forbidden-in-http-header-names)