# Configure Ingress controller to forward custom http headers

Tags: azure, kubernetes, .net-core, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

We are setting up an AKS cluster on Azure, following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls)

We are running 5 .Net Core API's behind an ingress controller, everything works fine, requests are being routed nicely.
However, in our SPA Frontend, we are sending a custom http header to our API's, this header never seems to make it to the API's, when we inspect the logging in AKS we see the desired http header is empty.
In development, everything works fine, we also see the http header is filled in our test environment in AKS, so i'm guessing ingress is blocking these custom headers.

Is there any configuration required to make ingress pass through custom http headers?

EDIT:

```
{
  "kind": "Ingress",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "myappp-ingress",
    "namespace": "myapp",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/myapp/ingresses/myapp-ingress",
    "uid": "...",
    "resourceVersion": "6395683",
    "generation": 4,
    "creationTimestamp": "2018-11-23T13:07:47Z",
    "annotations": {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "nginx",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/allow-headers": "My_Custom_Header", //this doesn't work
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size": "8m",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "tls": [
      {
        "hosts": [
          "myapp.com"
        ],
        "secretName": "..."
      }
    ],
    "rules": [
      {
        "host": "myapp.com",
        "http": {
          "paths": [
            {
              "path": "/api/tenantconfig",
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "tenantconfig-api",
                "servicePort": 80
              }
            },
            {
              "path": "/api/identity",
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "identity-api",
                "servicePort": 80
              }
            },
            {
              "path": "/api/media",
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "media-api",
                "servicePort": 80
              }
            },
            {
              "path": "/api/myapp",
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "myapp-api",
                "servicePort": 80
              }
            },
            {
              "path": "/app",
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "client",
                "servicePort": 80
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {
      "ingress": [
        {}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using the following configuration snippet:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  proxy_set_header My-Custom-Header $http_my_custom_header;
```

nginx makes all custom http headers available as embedded variable via the `$http_` prefix, see [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_)

Answer (score 4):

If I want my ingress controller pass a custom header to my backend service, I can use this annotation in my ingress rule

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  more_set_headers "Request-Id: $req_id";
```

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify this a bit? Request-Id would then be My_Custom_Header in my specific case? And what is the $req_id variable?
I tried setting this with My_Custom_Header: test, no luck unfortunately

Comment: this is an example, you need to pute the name of your custom header $my_costum_header and the desired name.

Comment: It put me in the right direction, I ended up using a configuration snippet for proxy_set_header

Comment: where does th $req_id come from. Does nginx controller set this variable for each request

Comment: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/log-format/

Answer (score 2):

By default ingress [doesn’t pass through headers with underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856136/why-do-http-servers-forbid-underscores-in-http-header-names).
You could set

```
enable-underscores-in-headers: true
```

See https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#enable-underscores-in-headers

Also Ingress [doesn’t pass through Authorization header](https://serverfault.com/questions/977426/how-to-keep-authentication-header-with-redirect-using-nginx-ingress-annotations)