# Spring Boot request header return null value

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, http

I have a spring boot project which has some Rest APIs in it. I have two custom headers named **`request_date`** and **`tenant`** respectively.

I am trying to read the value of these headers in an interceptor, but it reads the value for only **`tenant`** and returns null for **`request_date`**.

**Important**

- I use a filter to wrap the request object because I want to read the request body later.
- There is a filter to add CORS headers.

---

When I run my project on localhost and debug the code, I am successfully able to read both the headers' values.

However, when I deploy my application in production and make the request using postman or some other client, the **`request_date`** header's value is always read as null.

I am not sure what seems to be the problem with this. I am using **`Spring boot v1.5.10.RELEASE`** and **`JDK 1.8`**

**Note:**

- I have tried to rename the header to something like **`input_date`**. However, it still reads null.

---

The following is the relevant code

**TestInterceptor**

```
public class TestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        String requestDate = request.getHeader("request_date");
        String tenant = request.getHeader("Tenant");

        /*Perform some checks*/

        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

---

**CorsFilter**

```
public class ApiCorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers," +
                " X-Requested-With, Origin, X-Auth-Token, Tenant, request_date");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Auth-Token, Content-Disposition");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

---

**RequestCacheFilter**

```
public class RequestCacheFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest req = new RequestWrapper(request);
        String body = ((RequestWrapper) req).getBody();

        /*Do some operation*/

        filterChain.doFilter(req, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you call `request.getHeaderNames()`? Is it possible that null is set in the missing header?

Comment: I am not calling request.getHeaderNames(), yet I can read the value of the other headers. The problem is only specific to "request_date" header

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was with the nginx configuration.

I set the **`underscores_in_headers on;`** for the server and now it doesn't drop the headers with underscore in their names.

The solution suggested by @Karol Dowbecki works as well. When I renamed my header to **`requestDate`**, I was able to read the value successfully.

Answer (score 7):

Some network tools can drop headers that contain underscore in it's name. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22856867/1602555) underscore is a legal character but it's uncommon and sometimes tools require additional configuration to support it.

Rename your header to  `requestDate` or `request-date` and see if it helps. If it works without underscore than inspect network route between client and server e.g. maybe there is a proxy that drops them?