# Spring boot micro service dropping headers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx, kubernetes

I am facing an issue in spring boot. I developed a micro service and setup the infrastructure for it in kubernetes. I verified that my service is up and running by hitting a public URL which i exposed ( Example : https://abc/status).

But, now when i try to hit the get call which needs a header to be passed, I am receiving an exception which goes like this
Missing request header 'app_id' for method parameter of type String

While I execute this in local/within the pod, it is working fine.
Though I can confirm that the request has hit the service from the server logs. If you have faced something like this please help.

Answer (score 1):

I logged all the request headers and found out that only the headers with '_' is getting dropped. Then, when I explored in the same angle, I stumbled upon this link - [Spring Boot request header return null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923593/spring-boot-request-header-return-null-value/54924900#54924900) and found out that nginx is the culprit.

So, changing the nginx config or removing '_' from the service will fix this one.