# Log4j2 - How do I add runtime context so that all logging will contain that context?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

For example, say I have the application version that is determined at runtime. I want to have the application version appear for all log messages.

I know there is ThreadContext. My understanding is that if I do `ThreadContext.put("version", myAppVersion);`, then that will work until there is another thread. In which case the version would not be available.

Comment: is that version an [environment variable](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html)? you can define it as part of the log file name and/or the pattern you log. Though pretty sure it can be done with environment or system variables.

Comment: Ah yes, that will work. And thanks for that link. I feel like it's very hard to find information on the log4j2 website.

Answer (score 0):

Running `ThreadContext.put("version", "1.0.0")` in each thread is the only way in the Log4j API to provide the value in the context map of each event.

However if you are willing to implement a backend-specific solution, there are better solutions.

### Log4j Core

In the reference implementation of the Log4j API (called Log4j Core), you can implement the [`ContextDataProvider`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/javadoc/log4j-core/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/ContextDataProvider.html) interface and register it as Java service provider (cf. [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#developing-service-providers)).

The implementation might look like this:

```java
public class VersionContextDataProvider implements ContextDataProvider {

    private static final Map<String, String> MAP = Map.of("version", "1.0.0");

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> supplyContextData() {
        return MAP;
    }

    // Garbage-free optimization (optional)
    private static final StringMap STRING_MAP = new SortedArrayStringMap(MAP);

    static {
        STRING_MAP.freeze();
    }

    @Override
    public StringMap supplyStringMap() {
        return STRING_MAP;
    }
}
```

### Logback

Short of providing an alternative [`MDCAdapter`](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/spi/MDCAdapter.html) (cf. [How do I supply my own MDCAdapter to slf4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56110078/11748454)) I don't know how you can add additional values to the context map.

However since SLF4J 2.x a similar concept of key/value pair has been introduced (cf. [`LoggingEventBuilder#addKeyValue`](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/spi/LoggingEventBuilder.html#addKeyValue(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object))).