# How to send HTTP header field with "_" in its name?

Tags: swift, http

I have a set of header keys that I'm sending with a task. The issue comes when I'm looking on the server side and all the headers that contain a `_` are skipped. How can I insert the `_` in my header values? Using Unicode values? Using UTF-8? If so, where?

```
request.setValue("4435353", forHTTPHeaderField: "session_id")
request.setValue("08", forHTTPHeaderField: "channel-id")
request.setValue("5afde734-7655-406d-bda3-14ffa968d6ab", forHTTPHeaderField: "itau-client-id")
request.setValue("oO6oO3nW6iG8yV0kL6gU5yY1hE3qV6bH6yF0mK0tG4xX3qU2gD", forHTTPHeaderField: "itau-client-secret")
request.setValue("\(token_latam!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "token_latam")
request.setValue("itoken", forHTTPHeaderField: "application")
request.setValue("2017-12-12T12:30:00", forHTTPHeaderField: "timestamp")
request.setValue("c626ea51-edde-4172-8d16-1c2fd7700c13", forHTTPHeaderField: "itau-chave")
request.setValue("345353454", forHTTPHeaderField: "transaction_id")
request.setValue("\(encoded_operation!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "encoded_operation")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Server Side:

```
{
  "itau-chave": "c626ea51-edde-4172-8d16-1c2fd7700c13",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "timestamp": "2017-12-12T12:30:00",
  "itau-client-secret": "oO6oO3nW6iG8yV0kL6gU5yY1hE3qV6bH6yF0mK0tG4xX3qU2gD",
  "itau-client-id": "5afde734-7655-406d-bda3-14ffa968d6ab",
  "channel-id": "08",
  "application": "itoken",
  "accept-language": "en-us",
  "accept-encoding": "br, gzip, deflate",
  "user-agent": "ItauPassEmpresa/1 CFNetwork/975.0.3 Darwin/18.5.0",
  "content-type": "application/json"
}
```

Comment: Is `_` a valid character for a HTTP header field name?

Comment: this'll help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22856867/1042817

Answer (score 0):

just try to add `:` in prefix header name  for more info read this [HTTP::Headers](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Headers#NON-CANONICALIZED-FIELD-NAMES)

Comment: Like request.setValue("4435353", forHTTPHeaderField: ":session_id") ? Becase that's not working

Comment: your must handle this on server side