# How to force Ruby to respect underscore in Net::HTTP header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I force Ruby to respect an underscore in a `Net::HTTP` header?

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
headers = { 'api_key': 'my_private_key' }
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, headers)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = http.request(request)
```

In this case, the header that gets posted is actually `Api-Key` and the API I am trying to integrate with actually requires `api_key` -- case sensitive with the underscore.

Comment: This is going to be tricky. See the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/net/http/header.rb) here. Notice that all keys get made case-insensitive on their entry into the headers hash, and then a call to `each_capitalized` reconstitutes them. At best, you might be able to monkeypatch the call to `each_capitalized` in `GenericRequest` and replace it with your own logic.

Comment: If you intend to create a hash with symbol keys use colons. `{  api_key: 'my_private_key' }`. If you want strings use hashrockets `{  'api_key' => 'my_private_key' }`. Don't do `{ 'api_key': 'my_private_key' }` which looks like a hash with string keys but where they are actually coerced to symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Net::HTTP forces headers to meet the spec with regard to capitalization and punctuation. You can monkey patch it in a variety of ways (depending on the version of Net::HTTP) but those solutions are all fairly old at this point. Regardless, monkey patching third party libraries is a recipe for disaster.

Any client that relies on Net::HTTP, like HTTParty, has the same problem. You can read about some of these workarounds at https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/406, but again I don't recommend them.

You can read some more about issues with underscores in HTTP headers at [Why is my custom header not present sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58292976/3784008) and [Why do HTTP servers forbid underscores in HTTP header names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22856136/3784008).

The easier solution is to use [typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) which wraps libcurl rather than relying on Net::HTTP. Here's the quickest demonstration of how this works in typhoeus:

```
require 'typhoeus'
request = Typhoeus.get('www.example.com', headers: {'foo_bar' => 'baz'})
=> #<Typhoeus::Response:0x00007fdf3aa717e8 @options={:httpauth_avail=>0, :total_time=>0.336714, :starttransfer_time=>0.336496, :appconnect_time=>0.0, :pretransfer_time=>0.26573, :connect_time=>0.265662, :namelookup_time=>0.00133, :redirect_time=>0.0, :effective_url=>"www.example.com", :primary_ip=>"93.184.216.34", :response_code=>200, :request_size=>129, :redirect_count=>0, :return_code=>:ok, :response_headers=>"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nAge: 459799\r\nCache-Control: max-age=604800\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nDate: Tue, 24 Mar 2020 21:29:22 GMT\r\nEtag: \"3147526947+ident\"\r\nExpires: Tue, 31 Mar 2020 21:29:22 GMT\r\nLast-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT\r\nServer: ECS (ord/4CD5)\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nX-Cache: HIT\r\nContent-Length: 1256\r\n\r\n", :response_body=>"<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\" />\n    <style type=\"text/css\">\n    body {\n        background-color: #f0f0f2;\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, \"Segoe UI\", \"Open Sans\", \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n        \n    }\n    div {\n        width: 600px;\n        margin: 5em auto;\n        padding: 2em;\n        background-color: #fdfdff;\n        border-radius: 0.5em;\n        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);\n    }\n    a:link, a:visited {\n        color: #38488f;\n        text-decoration: none;\n    }\n    @media (max-width: 700px) {\n        div {\n            margin: 0 auto;\n            width: auto;\n        }\n    }\n    </style>    \n</head>\n\n<body>\n<div>\n    <h1>Example Domain</h1>\n    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>\n    <p><a href=\"https://www.iana.org/domains/example\">More information...</a></p>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n", :debug_info=>#<Ethon::Easy::DebugInfo:0x00007fdf3b3dbf40 @messages=[]>}, @request=#<Typhoeus::Request:0x00007fdf3aa72c60 @base_url="www.example.com", @original_options={:headers=>{"foo_bar"=>"baz"}, :method=>:get}, @options={:headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"Typhoeus - https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus", "foo_bar"=>"baz", "Expect"=>""}, :method=>:get, :maxredirs=>50}, @on_progress=[], @on_headers=[], @response=#<Typhoeus::Response:0x00007fdf3aa717e8 ...>, @on_complete=[], @on_success=[]>>
```

Then validate that the headers in your request were set properly:

```
request.request.options[:headers]
=> {
    "User-Agent" => "Typhoeus - https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus",
       "foo_bar" => "baz",
        "Expect" => ""
}
```

But even so, pay attention to the full stack that may be processing these headers as underscores are still at times problematic for various components in the stack.

I answered a similar question once before at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58459132/3784008.

Comment: Please see "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)".

Comment: Thanks @anothermh! I was afraid it wasnt going to be simple!