# kubernetes ingress controller not forwarding request headers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am working on a kubernetes cluster and problem faced is:

From UI/browser, I can see it is sending a request header called "**request_id**" please refer to image:

[image]

But while checking on backend it is unavailable. While searching through internet, I could see that people are talking about adding following entry to **Ingress** object:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header request_id "$req_id";
```

But it is generating a new value for this and not passing value submitted by browser.

Any ideas, what might be missing here?

Comment: I used your snippet configuration and one echoserver as backend and I can see the request id as x-request-id=c41db348719aa07093d9df53b2e8c24d

Comment: @c4f4t0r, that is a newly generated id by ingress controller. What I am looking for is, the same request-id; as sent by UI/browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, ingress-nginx-controller **drops any request headers that contains "_"** in them. You can find various threads which discuss this issue like,

[Why HTTP servers forbid underscores in HTTP header names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856136/why-http-servers-forbid-underscores-in-http-header-names)

So, I just enabled ingress controller to pass such request headers. This can be done by adding following entry to configmap "**nginx-configuration**"

```
data:
  enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
```

IMO, this is a much clean solution as there could be many applications that might use "_" in request headers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass a custom header to your backend, you need to use this kind of annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  more_set_headers "Request-Id: $request_id";
```

In your configuration you are using the variable $req_id, but you need to pass the variable sent by UI/browser.