# Flask App: API returns the same response for different requests

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, caching, flask

I have a Flask App that has multiple APIs, one of the APIs I've is accessed using POST request and takes data in the body along with some headers, for example, **student_id**. This API returns the student results based on the passed student_id in the headers.

I've run it in pycharm IDE (locally) and it works 100%, in which for each different student_id a different result is returned. otherwise (the student_id not passed) a bad request is returned.

but when it's deployed into AWS (Elasticbean stalk), the result is the same for any student_id even if there's no student_id present in the headers it still returns the result (the same result for the first request made on this API).

In my opinion, I guess it's a caching issue so I've tried to add a decorator @app.after_request but it didn't work

```
@application.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers['Last-Modified'] = str(http_date(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)))
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, 
    pre-check=0, max-age=0'"
    response.headers["Expires"] = '-1'
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, the above code in my question works well in which it disables the caching, but make sure to use a valid date format for HTTP (I've modified the code to work 100%).

The problem wasn't related to caching, it was an issue in which **someone of the headers was not passed to the servers**, that's because of AWS servers run on Nginx and Apache and

> underscores are not allowed in the headers

For complete details refer to this question [underscores are not allowed in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856136/why-http-servers-forbid-underscores-in-http-header-names)