# Google API Gateway throwing 400, Bad Request error for headers with underscore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, http-headers, google-api-gateway

I'm using Google API Gateway (available in beta) for my service. Facing an issue with the API Requests which have API Headers with underscore (`_`) in it's name e.g CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME. The API Gateway throws `400, Bad Request` for such requests.

The APIs work fine when the custom headers have hyphen (`-`) instead on underscore, e.g CUSTOM-HEADER-NAME.

It looks be to a configuration issue on the web server used by the API Gateway which is forbidding headers with underscores - [Why do HTTP servers forbid underscores in HTTP header names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856136/why-do-http-servers-forbid-underscores-in-http-header-names)

Since I don't have control over Google API Gateway's web server, is there a workaround to mitigate this issue and allow headers with underscores.

Note: The service is a legacy application being moved to GCP. So I don't really have the option to update the header formats as it would mean updating all the clients using this API.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the behavior you mentioned following the API Gateway [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/quickstart) and then issuing a request with underscores in headers like so `curl -H "MY_HEADER: XXX" https://API-GATEWAY-URL.`. I obtained the same result as yours. Therefore I have opened a feature request in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/175299604) so that this could be tracked.

You may be interested in examining other options such as Cloud Endpoints or Load Balancers to check if they could be an alternative in the meantime.

**UPDATE:** The use of underscores headers is now supported and could be achieved by adding the flag `--underscore_in_headers` as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-esp-v2-startup-options#underscore_in_headers).

Comment: Thanks. The documentation talks about using `--underscore_in_headers`  for ESPv2. Does it work for API Gateway? I tried with no luck on API gateway. Have commented the details on the issue tracker too.

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop here, I had created a support ticket with google for supporting the headers with underscores. They obliged to the request and the changes are now available out of the box.

No changes are needed from the API Gateway users.