# Parse and modify a request before it's routed in .net core 6 mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request

So an old program (windows exe) does a request to our site with this header:

"Accept-Charset[*space*]:ISO-8859-1"

And this throws a 400 Bad Request error. We cannot change that and remove the *space* (which would solve the nightmare) because that exe is already installed in a ton of computers.

This was not causing any issue when the web was a 20 year old ASP Web Forms, but now, the new NET 6 MVC doesn't like it.

The IAsyncActionFilter filter is not a solution as the BAD Request is returned before the query can even be routed.

Do you have any clue on how to parse that request removing the space or any other magic that can solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: You might be able to use IIS' _URL Rewriter_ functionality to alter that header too (you can use it for a lot more than just rewriting request-paths, it's a reverse-proxy too).

Comment: Yes it's that. I need to add a web.config file in my AppService app and the AppService IIS will apply the URL Rewrite. Now I need a magician that help me to tell IIS to ignore bad headers or to replace Accept-Charset<space>: ISO-8859-1" to Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1". Thank you Dai.

Comment: Are you able to run your old WebForms code and use VS's debugger to set a breakpoint when a request has the malformed `Accept-CharSet :`) header? I'm curious if `HttpContext.Request.Headers` shows the trailing space in the header name or not. As for the HTTP 400 error: do you know where/how ASP.NET Core is creating it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm don't have that code to test ;(
And the 400 Bad Request, I cannot debug this error because it's thrown at IIS level, way before I receive the request in ASP.NET.

Comment: ...so how did the old ASP.NET code work if it's IIS that rejects the request?

Comment: That's a good question. Old code was hosted in our own IIS. Now the Web is hosted in Azure App Service. Maybe there are different default filters or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something called [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) (*msdn*).

**In short**, it gives you access to the request/response pipeline - so you can perform some actions with request before it reaches your controller and with response before it is passed to a client.

*Implementation*

In your *Startup.cs*:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ///           ///
        /// Your code ///
        ///           ///
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ///           ///
        /// Your code ///
        ///           ///

        app.UseMiddleware<HttpHeadersAligner>();
    }
}
```

*HttpHeadersAligner.cs*

```
public class HttpHeadersAligner
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public HttpHeadersAligner(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        ///
        /// Your code
        /// 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that does not solve the problem. The thing brakes before this middleware is activated as IIS cannot parse the request. When I curl my URL and put that space before the colon, the program doesn't even stop there.

Comment: curl --header "Accept-Charset<space>: ISO-8859-1" https://localhost:51818/

Answer (score 0):

### Using IIS' *URL Rewrite 2.0*:

- **NOTE:** The OP said their problem is that old client software is sending HTTP requests with a malformed `Accept-Charset` header (it has a space `0x20`) after the `Accept-Charset` header name but *before* the colon (and no space after the colon), i.e. `"Accept-Charset :ISO-8859-1"`.

  - *I do not know* if IIS' URL Rewrite extension will correctly match this header. My answer is written in the assumption that it does. YMMV.
- You will need version 2.0 (or later) of the IIS *URL Rewrite* extension to manipulate request and response headers (amongst other things) before ASP.NET Core sees the request.

  - *Azure App Services* (aka *Azure Websites*) already has this extension installed.
  - Download version 2.1 from https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
- Recommended reading:

  - URL Rewriter 1.0 documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference
  - URL Rewriter 2.0 documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference

    - This article only covers *new* functionality in version 2.0; the documentation for version 1.0 still applies to 2.0: use the 1.0 documentation for the basic URL rewriter functionality, and the 2.0 documentation only for more advanced topics like ARR, etc.
- *IIS URL Rewrite 2.0* can edit (add, set, edit, and remove) request and response headers via their *HTTP Server Variable* representations.

  - [Request headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#using-server-variables-in-rewrite-rules) are identified and matched by strings of the form `HTTP_{UPPER_SNAKE_CASE_HEADER_NAME}`.

    - The underscores ("`_`") will match dashes ("`-`") in the request header name (this does not introduce ambiguity [as underscores will not normally appear in header names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856136/why-do-http-servers-forbid-underscores-in-http-header-names)).
  - Response headers are identified by strings of the form `RESPONSE_{HEADER_NAME}`.
  - For example:

    - Match the `Content-Type` request header with `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE`.
    - Match the `Content-Type` response header with `RESPONSE_Content-Type`.
  - In your case, to match `Accept-Charset :ISO-8859-1` *I assume* that IIS will either strip the space by itself and match `HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET` - or - IIS will allow and match a trailing literal space or XML entitized space (`&#x20;`) as `"HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET "` or `"HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET&#x20;"` respectively.

    - I have not tested this, however.
- **NOTE:** In order to allow a `<rewrite>` configuration to edit HTTP headers, you need to edit IIS' `applicationHost.config` file (which defines server-level settings and Website configuration) to add the HTTP server variable representation of those request/response header names to the `<allowedServerVariables>` list.

  - In *Azure App Services* (aka *Azure Websites*) you can do this with your `applicationHost.xdt` file, placed at `D:\home\site\applicationHost.xdt` - and the file should look like this:

    ```xml
    <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <allowedServerVariables>
                     <!-- I'm trying different patterns so that the trailing space will hopefully be matched. -->
                     <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                     <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET " xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                     <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET&#x20;" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                 </allowedServerVariables>
             </rewrite>
         </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
    ```
  - In other hosting scenarios, consult your hosting provider.
- Here's something that I feel should work...

  - I assume `<action type="None" />` will still edit the HTTP request headers, but if not, try `<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />` (which will rewrite the request URL to itself, a NOOP, basically).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rule name="ClearAcceptCharset0" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET" value="" />
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET " value="" />
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET&#x20;" value="" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="ClearAcceptCharset1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET }" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET" value="" />
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET " value="" />
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET&#x20;" value="" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="ClearAcceptCharset2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET&#x20;}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET" value="" />
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET " value="" />
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET&#x20;" value="" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

- HTH, YMMV, etc.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your great response. Following the instructions, I connected to the AppService FTP and modified the file found in /SiteExtensions/applicationHost.xdt adding both samples, but no way ;(